# Как правильно объявить user в flask-login

Tags: python, flask

Получается залогинется, но когда шлю не верный логин или пароль, то получаю ошибку

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_active'

Я запутался с **g.user**, который объявляется до @app.route

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user
```

и не кажется правильным решение:

```
user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data,password=form.password.data).first()
```

models:

```
from app import db,unicode,UserMixin

ROLE_USER = 0
ROLE_ADMIN = 1

class User(UserMixin,db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index = True, unique = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index = True, unique = True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), index = True)
    role = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, default=ROLE_USER)

    def __init__(self, id, username, email, password, role):
        self.id = id
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.role = role

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'ID: %r ' % (self.id) + ' USERNAME: %r ' % (self.username) + ' EMAIL: %r ' % (self.email) + ' PASSWORD: %r ' % (self.password) + ' ROLE: %r ' % (self.role)
```

views:

```
@lm.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(id)

@app.route('/login', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def login():
    if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index', title=g.user.username))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data,password=form.password.data).first()
        print('USER :' + str(user))
        print('G.USER :' + str(g.user))
        print('USER LOGIN IS : ' + str(login_user(user)))
        login_user(user)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

forms:

```
class LoginForm(Form):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('New Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField('Remember me', default=False)
```

Comment: Ну так вы в `login_user` отправляете `None` зачем-то, вот и падает

Comment: Иначе говоря, ни WTForms, ни Flask-Login не делают (и не могут делать и не должны делать) проверку существования пользователя и правильности пароля, это всё вы должны делать сами

Comment: @andreymal в [документации](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) в разделе How it Works написано 
**"It should return None (not raise an exception) if the ID is not valid. "**

Comment: @andreymal извиняюсь за офтоп, но зачем тогда в фреймворке вся эта "магия" ?

Comment: Во-первых, не путайте `load_user` и `login_user`

Comment: Во-вторых, если вам хочется всё готовенькое и чтоб самому ничего не делать, то попробуйте Django :) У Flask идеология такая: как вы хотите, так вы и собираете своё приложение по частям. Судя по уровню вопросов, собирать у вас не очень получается, это сейчас не для вас.

Comment: Руками это сделать у меня получается, просто я хочу сделать это всё максимально красиво. Хочется использоваться все возможности flask-login.

Comment: Возможность Flask-Login — это привязка объекта пользователя к сессии, и всё. Через `login_user` вы указываете, какой именно объект привязать, Flask-Login достаёт оттуда id и сохраняет его в сессии, а при следующих запросах к сайту он вызывает `load_user`, чтобы по id, сохранённому в сессии, загрузить объект снова. Вот и всё, больше ничего тут нет. В `load_user` вы возвращать None можете. Но передавать None в `login_user` вы НЕ можете.